# AWS API Gateway SDK generation error at least one operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to generate an SDK for am API Gateway that is already deployed and has 2 stages created in API Gateway console.
However, when I try to create an SDK from it using the API Gateway Console, I encounter the following error.

```
Generation failed during SETUP stage: Must have at least one operation present in the API
```

Has anyone encountered this error? I do not see any thing else on the AWS Console.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. Could you please share your solution / fix?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a GET method under /, and link it to mock integration should solve this issue.